# Haskell: Not in scope: ‘listDirectory’

Tags: haskell

I am using GHC version 7.10.2. When i try to use listDirectory function, I am getting following error.

```
Prelude System.Directory> :t listDirectory

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: ‘listDirectory’
```

I am also updated my packages using 'cabal update'.

**Reference**
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.5.1/docs/System-Directory.html

Comment: It's really weird to see people voting to close this for "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". That's not even close to be the case here. Please take time to read the question carefully before using close votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`listDirectory` wasn't added until [version 1.2.5.0](https://github.com/haskell/directory/releases/tag/v1.2.5.0) last December. Take a look at your version of the `directory` package by running `ghc-pkg list`, or if you are using Stack, run `stack exec ghc-pkg list`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My directory package version is "directory-1.2.2.0". Is "cabal update' don't update the directory package ? Can you tell me how to get the latest package...

Comment: You'll need to add `directory >= 1.2.5.0` to your `build-depends` section of the .cabal file. If you're using Stack, then add `'directory-1.2.5.1'` to the `extra-deps` section in your `stack.yaml` file. (if you're just using cabal, I don't recall the extra dependency step off hand)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Command "cabal install 'directory-1.2.5.0' " solves the issue.